# SAP Successfactors Non-Standard OCN Provider Integration

Tags: odata, sap-successfactors

I'm working on an integration project connecting **SAP Successfactors** with a **Non-Standard OCN Provider**. I'm using **OData API** to push course listings into Successfactors LMS. After APM Sync, the OCN items are visible on SF, but the open content sessions for each item is showing as

> "There are no content network sessions for this item"

Course schedule information is also pushed along with the payload parameters of the OData API

```
"schedule": [
            {
                "startDate": 1572393600,
                "endDate": 1572480000,
                "active": true,
                "duration": "2 days"
            }
        ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Open Content Network (OCN)** is a group of **Massive Online Open Course (MOOC)** partners who can provide content to SAP SuccessFactors LMS. MOOC courses will not have specific start time and end time as they are online courses and are different than the **Instructor-led** standard offerings. In order to convert OCN items into standard offerings, the item type (classification) of these items must to be converted into "Instructor-led". After that these courses can be added into scheduled offerings and then the date/time segments will start appearning.